# What are the main limitations of Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

What, if any, are the main limitations of using Xamarin over using native tools (libraries / languages) directly? I.e. are all api's available for media / maps / gates etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin provides bindings for all of the native platform API's of iOS and Android, including media, maps, wearables/watch, HealthKit, etc.  You can also create your own binding libraries if you have a native (Java/ObjC) library you would like to use in your Xamarin app, but the vendor does not provide their own bindings.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/